# How do I tell cmake I want my project to link libraries statically?

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to build an OpenCV-based project using CMake, running on Linux. So far my `CMakeLists.txt` files looks something like

```
FIND_PACKAGE (OpenCV REQUIRED)
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (my-executable ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

but this results in dynamically linked libraries. How do I link with static libraries?

Comment: How do you point "CMake at a static OpenCV build"? My build has both static and shared libs.

Comment: see answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10709424/6069

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You build static OpenCV libraries by just setting the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` flag to false in CMake. Then all you need to do to build your own application with those static libraries is to add a dependency on OpenCV in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
FIND_PACKAGE (OpenCV REQUIRED)
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (your-application ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

and CMake will take care of everything.

Comment: It's `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`, not `_LIBRARIES`. :-)

Comment: I corrected BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES to BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.

Comment: At least with CLion under Windows (CLion 2016.3 EAP) which comes bundled with CMake 3.6.1, when building OpenCV 3.1.0, this was the only way of those listed here which caused CMake to build OpenCV as static rather than shared libraries.  Note that attempts to enable this option by editing CMakeLists.txt failed; only by editing the CMake cache via CLion's Cache window and clicking the *Apply Changes and Reload Project* icon was I able to get my CLion/CMake combination to accept `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`.  Not sure if this is a problem with CLion that should be documented.

Comment: This only works if you're building opencv as well. Not in the case where you're using preinstalled opencv libraries.

Answer (score 13):

Actually this issue seems to have already been fixed in the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` that comes with OpenCV.  All you have to do is define `OpenCV_STATIC` in your `CMakeLists.txt`.  I.e.

```
set(OpenCV_STATIC ON)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

Comment: What does 'find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)' do?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04. In which version was this fixed?

Answer (score 6):

To link everything statically, I believe you're looking for `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` (add `-static`).

Are you using the 'simple method' of OpenCVConfig.cmake? or the older FindOpenCV.cmake?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK that's a bit tricky, because CMake, more precisely the find_library command, prefers shared libs and finds those if both shared and static are available.

I'm still looking for a good solution myself to be able to compile binaries "as static as possible", but I've found no elegant solution yet. The only way it would surely work is to implement everything through custom FindXXXX modules.

Comment: The only way I now is to change searched library suffixes: 
`set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})`
before `find_library()`.

FindBoost and has special option to force the use of static libraries (`Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`), but it also works internally by changing `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`.

Answer (score 3):

on the add_library line specify static. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html

Correction since you are looking to link against a static library I would look into the
[CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html) property

Comment: I think the add_library command is to generate an output binary. In this case, specifying STATIC causes it to generate .a.

Comment: The static keyword for add_library specifies what type of library it generates, it is not for when generating the binary.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but I thought the OP was trying to link with a static library, not generate one.

Comment: yep, I'm not creating a library, I want to link (statically) to the OpenCV libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Note that **gcc refuses to link** if you pass the -static option, but you have dynamic libs in the link arguments - which you will if you just simply use FindOpenCV.cmake and this picks up the dynamic libs (I don't know how OpenCVConfig.cmake behaves though)...

Answer (score -1):

```
SET (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```