# How to build an application using CMake that statically link to OpenCV on MacOS?

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, static-linking

I tried everything I could to build my application using OpenCV static library on MacOS but at the end of the build I had no error but `otool -L` showed me that it was not working:

```
build/src/lut_loader:
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_gapi.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_stitching.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_alphamat.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_aruco.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_bgsegm.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_bioinspired.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_ccalib.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn_superres.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)                                                [0/1973]
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn_superres.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_dpm.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_face.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_freetype.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_fuzzy.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_hfs.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_img_hash.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_intensity_transform.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_line_descriptor.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_mcc.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_quality.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_rapid.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_reg.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_rgbd.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_saliency.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_sfm.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_stereo.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_structured_light.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_superres.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_surface_matching.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_tracking.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_videostab.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_viz.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_wechat_qrcode.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_xphoto.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_shape.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_datasets.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_plot.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_text.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_ml.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_optflow.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_video.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_objdetect.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_calib3d.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_dnn.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_features2d.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_flann.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_photo.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.408.dylib (compatibility version 408.0.0, current version 4.8.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1500.65.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.100.3)
```

Here is my current CMakeLists.txt

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build using shared libraries" OFF)
list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/local/lib/")
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a" ".lib")
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)

if (BUILD_CUDA)
    find_package(CUDAToolkit)
endif()

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)
message(STATUS "Boost include dir: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS false)
set(OpenCV_STATIC ON)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

if (BUILD_CUDA)
    message(STATUS "CUDA include dir: ${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")
    set(INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${INCLUDE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
    set(INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    #opencv_core
    #opencv_imgcodecs
    Boost::program_options
    Eigen3::Eigen
)

add_subdirectory(${SOURCE_DIR}/ImageProcessing)
add_subdirectory(${SOURCE_DIR}/TaskDispatcher)
add_subdirectory(${SOURCE_DIR}/DataLoader)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell cmake I want my project to link libraries statically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755482/how-do-i-tell-cmake-i-want-my-project-to-link-libraries-statically)